# Lego Mindstorm NXT, Cocoa, and HiTechnic Sensors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, robotics, lego-mindstorms

I've taken the existing code from [this project](http://code.google.com/p/legonxtremote/), and very happy with it so far.

I'm now however in a position where I need to make use of some third-party sensors which I've purchased from [hitechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com), such as an accelerometer, a gyroscope, and a 3D compass - to mention a few.

I'm not sure where to start now, but what I need to do is add to my existing code base (which is based on the [this](http://code.google.com/p/legonxtremote/)), and effectively glue my framework to the new hardware.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I can't find any APIs from the device manufacturer, (but I have emailed them and asked - no reply yet).

I've also started to document my findings on [this](http://ai.autonomy.net.au/wiki/Project/Framework/Nimachine) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've had a look.  The analog sensors, such as the Gyro, are dead easy...

I pretty much just reused that of another analog sensor - the Light sensor...

```
- (void)setupGyroscopicSensor:(UInt8)port {
    [self setInputMode:port
                  type:kNXTGyroscope
                  mode:kNXTRawMode];
}
```

For polling, I used the generic polling method...

```
- (void)pollSensor:(UInt8)port interval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
```

...from the LegoNXTRemote code.

The digital ones are not as easy - specially to someone who has zero sw/hw experience. Here is the working ultrasonic sensor code, setup, and for polling.  I will only write the prototype of these methods and a git clone for those interested in the full code at the end.

```
- (void)setupUltrasoundSensor:(UInt8)port continuous:(BOOL)continuous;
- (void)getUltrasoundByte:(UInt8)port byte:(UInt8)byte;
- (void)pollUltrasoundSensor:(UInt8)port interval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
```

Note how it has it's own dedicated method for polling.  So, now the question is how to write one for the accelerometer.

The information you get when buying the sensor is a table mapping addresses to content:

```
42H (byte) -> X-axis upper 8 bits
43H (byte) -> X-axis upper 8 bits
44H (byte) -> X-axis upper 8 bits
45H (byte) -> X-axis lower 8 bits
46H (byte) -> X-axis lower 8 bits
47H (byte) -> X-axis lower 8 bits
```

...looking at the ultrasonic sensor, I can see references to `0x42` - which I am guessing is where the address goes, but that's all i can *guess* right now.

I'll let you know if I get any progress on this.

---

Okay, here's where it's at with the Accelerometer.

I first send the device the following message...

```
0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x08, 0x02, 0x42
```

What that means respectively (I'm could well be wrong) is...

```
kNXTRawMode
kNXTGetInputValues
kNXTRet     //. Meaning we expect a return value
kNXTLSWrite //. As opposed to read
port        //. Port 0x03 --> Port 4
txLength
rxLength
//. message...
0x02 //. Set the I2C slave address
0x42 //. Set the register we're interested in
```

Next we send a read request...

```
0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x03
```

And to that we get a response...

```
0x03, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0f, 0xe0
```

...and that ends with an error.

Here's a chunk of log...

```
           libNXT[0x02]: Attempting to connect to NXT...
           libNXT[0x02]: Open sequence initiating...
           libNXT[0x02]: Channel Opening Completed
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x06, 0x00, 0x80, 0x03, 0x0b, 0x02, 0xf4, 0x01, 
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x05, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x82, 0x1e, 
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector does NOT respond to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTBatteryLevel:batteryLevel:
 startPollingSensor: setup sensor
 startPollingSensor: start polling
           libNXT[0x02]: Polling Port 3
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x08, 0x02, 0x42, 
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x03, 
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x03, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0f, 0xe0, 
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xf status=0xe0
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0e, 0xe0, 0x00, 
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xe status=0xe0
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector does NOT respond to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
           libNXT[0x02]: Polling Port 3
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x08, 0x02, 0x42, 
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x03, 
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x03, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0f, 0xe0, 
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xf status=0xe0
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0e, 0xe0, 0x00, 
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xe status=0xe0
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector does NOT respond to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
           libNXT[0x02]: Polling Port 3
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x08, 0x02, 0x42, 
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x03, 
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x03, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0f, 0xe0, 
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xf status=0xe0
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0e, 0xe0, 0x00, 
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xe status=0xe0
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector does NOT respond to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
Error while running hook_stop:
           libNXT[0x08]: >>> :0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x03,
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x03, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0f, 0xe0,
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xf status=0xe0
           libNXT[0x08]: <<< :0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0e, 0xe0, 0x00,
           libNXT[0x08]: @selector responds to NXTOperationError:operation:status:
 nxt error: operation=0xe status=0xe0
```

This is all based on the example code from [here](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NAC1040), which is as follows...

```
SetSensorLowspeed(IN_1);
int count;

int xval;
int yval;
int zval;

byte inI2Ccmd[];
byte outbuf[];
while (TRUE) {
    ArrayInit(inI2Ccmd, 0, 2); // set the buffer to hold 10 values (initially all are zero)
    inI2Ccmd[0] = 0x02; // set values in the array
    inI2Ccmd[1] = 0x42;
    count=8;                                  //read count set to 8 bytes
    I2CBytes(IN_1, inI2Ccmd, count, outbuf);  //read the acceleration sensor on port 1
    xval=outbuf[0];                           //load x axis upper 8 bits
    yval=outbuf[1];                           //load Y axis upper 8 bits
    zval=outbuf[2];                           //load z axis upper 8 bits
    if (xval > 127) xval-=256;                //convert x to 10 bit value
    xval=xval*4 + outbuf[3];
    if (yval > 127) yval-=256;                //convert y to 10 bit value
    yval=yval*4 + outbuf[4];
    if (zval > 127) zval-=256;                //convert z to 10 bit value
    zval=zval*4 + outbuf[5];
    ...

}
```

---

Awesome! Looks like it's working now - I just need to fiddle with the output to extract the actual X, Y and Z readings.

If it does work, I'll let you all know, but until I've proved it, I'll leave this ticket open.

---

Okay, it looks like it's now working, but there's enough error in the sensor, and I've yet to prove that I've really resolved this.  Here's the code snippet:

```
SInt8 *outbuf = malloc(48);
[data getBytes:outbuf length:6];
SInt16 x = outbuf[0]; x <<= 2; x += outbuf[3];
SInt16 y = outbuf[1]; y <<= 2; y += outbuf[4];
SInt16 z = outbuf[2]; z <<= 2; z += outbuf[5];
free(outbuf);
[self setSensorTextField:port
                   value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%d, %d, %d>",
                          x, y, z]];
```

If anyone is interested in this, I invite you to download the source and try it out - I'm yet to prove scientifically that this is actually correct, even though first glance it looks ok.

---

Okay, I've done some testing - it looks good.  I've converted the values to G's, as per the instructions that came with the device - stating that 1 G ~ 200 units (I wish they did a little better than ~200, some indication of the error would have been nice).

```
//. Acceleration in G's
SInt8 *outbuf = malloc(48);
[data getBytes:outbuf length:6];
SInt16 x = outbuf[0]; x <<= 2; x += outbuf[3]; float gX = x/200.f;
SInt16 y = outbuf[1]; y <<= 2; y += outbuf[4]; float gY = y/200.f;
SInt16 z = outbuf[2]; z <<= 2; z += outbuf[5]; float gZ = z/200.f;
free(outbuf);
[self setSensorTextField:port
                   value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f",
                          gX, gY, gZ]];
```

If you position the device as per the vendor page, you can see each access hit an acceleration reading of ~ 1.02f.

I think I can close this off now and work on cleaning up the framework.

---

The code can be checked out at:

```
git clone git://git.autonomy.net.au/nimachine Nimachine
```

Answer (score 2):

I heard back from HiTechnic today, and with their permission, I'm posting their response for everyone here.

```
Hi Nima,

There are two types of sensors, digital and analog.  The Analog sensors you
can basically read like you would the LEGO light sensor.  If you have that
working then you can read the HiTechnic analog sensors.  These include the
EOPD, Gyro as well as the Touch Multiplexer.

For the TMUX there is [sample NXC code][1] on the product info page.
You should be able to use that as a basis if you want to support this device.

The other sensors are digital I2C sensors.  Most of these sensors have I2C
register information on their respective product information page and/or it
was included on a sheet that came with the sensor.  First of all, to make
these sensors work with your framework you need to have I2C communications
working.  After that it will be a matter of creating your own API that uses
the I2C interface with the sensors.  I recommend that you download and look
at Xander Soldaat's RobotC driver suite for the HiTechnic sensors.  You will
find this near the bottom of the HiTechnic downloads page.

Regards,
Gus
HiTechnic Support
```

References:

- [Sample NXC code](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NTX1060)
- [Xander's Blog](http://mightor.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/robotc-i2c-howto-part-i/)

Comment: While this doesn't answer my question, it's a good start - as soon as I get time to follow up on it, and get some results, I will post back here and update everyone.